# Mvc razor checkbox states

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, checkbox

Very newbie question, but I'm finding it difficult to understand how checkbox States are maintained after a form post in razor mvc 5.

I've done it in PHP with session variables but for the life of me, can't find an easy to understand way in razor.

My situation is, view with checkboxes, form post handled by controller and postback to view with checkbox States from before form post set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Your controller you can check bool property of your checkbox by
if (model.check)
            {
                do something
            }